# Post status update to Facebook page (Fan site)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-page

I've seen all the posts here on stackoverflow about posting status updates to a page's wall (not a user's wall); but all appear to be out of date as none of them address the issue with the new Open Stream API. All the research I've done on Google leads me to the same end: Out of date tutorials that end up saying that the current implementation isn't perfect but "hopefully when the Open Stream API is released, it'll be better."

Well, Open Stream is here. Any ideas how to leverage it and post a simple status update to a Fan site page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Stream API's official release was two days ago. That explains the lack of tutorials.

- Here is a good intro into Open Stream API http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=288
- Here a Overview Wiki Tutorial  http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_the_Open_Stream_API
- The stream.publish function is used for posting at pages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

> If you
>   specified a session_key, and that
>   session user is a Page admin, then you
>   can specify a Page ID here to publish
>   to one Page for which the session user
>   is an admin.